# Plotting inside Matlab Function Block for real time signals in Simulink

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, real-time, simulink

I have a simulation running on `Simulink` and output signals change during simulation. I want to plot them at every step. What I can do is to use `to Workspace` blocks to transfer them to `Matlab`, but then I can only plot after the simulation finishes. I would like to plot the value at every instant of the simulation.

What I tried:

Create a figure in advance as: `figure(1)` and plot a static graph on it. Then I use

`Matlab` function inside `Simulink` :

```
function fcn(x,y)
coder.extrinsic('plot')
plot(x,y,'s','Markersize',8,'MarkerFaceColor','g','erasemode','background')
```

Where x and y are my signals as input to matlab function block. However this results in plotting x and y in every timestep, but I would like to plot only the last value of the signal on the figure and delete the previous ones, in other words refresh the plot so that it is going to act as an animation. How can I achieve that? Thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain why you're not just using a scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code should work, with a few minor modifications:

I would do the following if I were you:

In the model callbacks, define your figure in the `InitFcn` callback:

```
fig_h = figure;
ax_h = axes;
set(ax_h,'Xlim',[0 12],'YLim',[0 12]) % or whatever axes limits you want
```

Then in your MATLAB Function block:

```
function fcn(x,y)
%#codegen
coder.extrinsic('plot')
plot(x,y,'s','Markersize',8,'MarkerFaceColor','g','erasemode','background')
set(gca,'XLim',[0 12],'Ylim',[0 12]) % or whatever axes limits you want
```

Comment: First I thought that Navan's solution fits better and actually it works well. The problem is I could not figure out how to plot two different signals on the same plot with that approach. But with your solution, I can but `Matlab` function block as much as I want to plot multiple signals on the same grid, which is desired. But also I cannot remove previous points from the grid, erasemode is not working as I expected. Previous points are not deleted. Do you have an idea? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need little more elaborate function than just calling plot to animate your data. You should create a plot_fcn and make that function extrinsic. An example implementation of plot_fcn assuming scalar inputs with range 0 to 100 is

```
function plot_fcn(x,y)

persistent f h
if isempty(f)
    f = figure;
    h = plot(x,y,'s','Markersize',8,'MarkerFaceColor','g','erasemode','background');
    axis([0 100 0 100]);
    axis manual
end
figure(f);
set(h, 'XData', x);
set(h, 'YData', y);
```

You can then call this function as

```
function fcn(x,y)
coder.extrinsic('plot_fcn')
plot_fcn(x,y);
```

Also checkout other questions regarding animation in MATLAB plots.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I was not aware of using the variable type persistent, which was the solution in my case. I also removed the figure(f) line because then it is switching back to that figure at every iteration step which makes impossible to reach the main simulink window to stop the simulation or check some values. One small question about the plot_fcn(x,y) : I would like to plot two different data on the same plot. Say I have (X1 Y1) and (X2 Y2) pair and I want to plot those with different colors, however this figure does not allow me to do it. Do you have a recommendation?